# Dividing a quantity into N dimensions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In some accounting systems, it's common to want to allocate costs to "objects" in different "dimensions". A dimension could be something like departments (Sales and Marketing), projects (Project A, B, and C) or cost centers (New York, London, Madrid, Berlin). There can be an arbitrary number $N$ of dimensions, and each dimension $i$ can hold $n_i$ items.

My question is, given a template for allocating the share of some cost $X$ to each object in each dimension, how can I, in general, split the total cost into transactions so that the costs are correctly allocated in each dimension?

I have the following conditions

- A transaction can be associated with one object per dimension
- The sum of all transactions, and across any dimension, must still be $X$
- I want as few transactions as possible

So, concretely, my questions are:

- What's an efficient algorithm to do this?
- Is there always a unique answer?

For example, in a given month, my employee Alice might be allocated as follows.

```
| Dimension  | Object    | Allocation |
| :--------- | :-------- | ---------: |
| Department | Sales     |         75 |
| Department | Marketing |         25 |
| Project    | A         |         80 |
| Project    | B         |         10 |
| Project    | C         |         10 |
| City       | New York  |         50 |
| City       | London    |         30 |
| City       | Madrid    |         15 |
| City       | Berlin    |          5 |
```

My total cost for Alice is 100. I would like to create transactions, such as the following which allocate this across the different dimensions.

```
| Department | Project | City     | Value |
| :--------- | :------ | :------- | ----: |
| Sales      | A       | New York |    50 |
| Sales      | A       | London   |    25 |
| Marketing  | A       | London   |     5 |
| Marketing  | B       | Madrid   |    10 |
| Marketing  | C       | Madrid   |     5 |
| Marketing  | C       | Berlin   |     5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trivial way, but it probably doesn't give what you are after.  You can assume that the distribution across each dimension is independent of its distribution across any other dimension.  As you have two departments, three projects, and four cities, you would come up with $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4=24$ transactions.  Sales/A/New York would get $0.75 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 100=30$ and so on.

What is probably more like you were thinking is a table with fewer transactions that represented what work was done on which project in what city.  You could ask Alice to keep track of her time with all three dimensions, then just make the necessary transactions from the record.  That would let you know that project A was done in New York and London, while B and C were done in Madrid and Berlin.  Whether that data is useful enough to be worth the cost of keeping track of it is something you need to answer.

Your table seems to have been made by putting the values in each dimension in some order, then assigning a transaction of the side that uses up one of the values.  It is a reasonable way to create an example.  This will always work, but probably has no relationship to reality.

You can't look at the first table and find a unique second table without the assumption in the first paragraph or some more data.  You should determine the purpose of the second table, then it will be easier to figure out how to get the data to make it and how accurate it will be.

Comment: In my example, we just got an invoice for the total amount. The invoice simply attributes the total cost to Alice, and we want to distribute this cost across various dimensions.

It doesn't really matter what the individual transactions say; they're just ledger entries. However, I'd like for there to be as few as possible.

Comment: Your heuristic is a reasonable one.  Finding the true minimum is similar to the bin-packing problem and probably NP-hard.  It appears you have listed the objects in each dimension in decreasing order of size, then at each stage taken the minimum of the amount left to create a line, subtracting that off and replacing objects when the amount left goes to zero.  Depending on the data, there may be more efficient ways, but it is probably not worth the effort to find them